# e.preventDefault() not working on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When my HTML form is submitted, the webpage reloads even though I have the `e.preventDefault()` command in my submission function.

```js
$("#room-code-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="room-code-form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you check for errors in console log? it should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use `on()` or `bind()` with jquery instead of addeventlistener.
2. Also `return false` from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation on the passed jQuery.Event object.

```js
$("#room-code-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="room-code-form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using submit function. You need to bind it inside Document Ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#room-code-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="room-code-form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

or

```
$("#room-code-form").submit(function(e) {
   return false;
});
```